# How to validate claim with one tail hypothesis testing.

Tags: statistics

A poll claims that $49 \%$ of adults purchase life insurance. A random sample of $50$ adult shows that only $38 \%$ purchased life insurance. Use a one tail test with $\alpha =.05$ to test the validity of this claim.

I don't want the answer I just need help with what I have to do next, so far I found the $z$ score using the following formula:
$$z=\frac{\hat{p}-p_0}{\sqrt{\frac{p_0(1-p_0)}{n}}}$$

Now I don't know what to do, do I use a right tail z normal distribution table or a t distribution table with 50 degrees of freedom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're approximating the binomial distribution with the normal distribution (this approximation is good enough). Hence you'll need to use a normal distribution table, not a t-table.